# Trigger Snapshot in Xamarin profiling using Commandline

Tags: xamarin.android, adb

I use below technique to take heap snapshot from android device for my App.

1. Enable heapshot logging:

   adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile log:heapshot
2. Start your app. (If your app was already running before (1), kill and restart it.)
3. Use your app.
4. Grab the profile data for your app:

   adb pull /data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.**override**/profile.mlpd
   @PACKAGE_NAME@ is the package name of your application, e.g. if your package is FooBar.FooBar-Signed.apk, then @PACKAGE_NAME@ will be FooBar.FooBar.

When I open generated mlpd file in Xamarin profiler, it shows over all allocations, but does not show any Snapshots / Live objects.

**How to trigger a snapshot through command line?** Is there any adb command or any possibility to usage for particular snapshot? since i am automating over all scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Very old post but still posting answer as Might help others in need:
**Use below command:**

1. First set the property

   adb shell setprop debug.mono.profile log:alloc,maxframes=2,heapshot=10000ms
2. ReStart app & after operations/test cases use below command to pull file

   adb shell pull /data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.**override**/profile.mlpd  profile1.mlpd
3. After profiling is done force-stop the app to stop the profiling

   adb shell am  force-stop @PACKAGE_NAME@

*For more info please refer link:*
https://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/profiler/